# how to use dojo in struts2 submit form data to action display the result in same jsp page

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, dojo

I am trying to submit a form and display the output in the same page.
I am using struts2 and its dojo plugin to solve my need. I was able to display the result in the same page but the action is called automatically once again after the button click action occurs. Hence it will overwrite the output that I just got from the submission of the form.

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<sx:head/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enqDetails(){
        alert("ok");
        //document.firstForm.action = 'firstAction';
        //document.firstForm.submit();  
        <s:url id="urlTestAction" action="firstAction"/>
        dojo.event.topic.publish("show_detail");
        document.getElementById('sxDivId1').style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> this is index page!!</h1>
    <s:form id="firstForm" name="firstForm">
            <s:textfield name="username" label="enter username"/>
            <s:submit onclick="enqDetails()"></s:submit>
    </s:form>
    <sx:div id="sxDivId1" href="%{urlTestAction}" listenTopics="show_detail" formId="firstForm" loadingText="Please Wait...." showLoadingText="true" cssStyle="display:none;">
    </sx:div> 

</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml

```
  <action name="firstAction" class="action.FirstAction" method="first">
    <result name="success">/second.jsp</result>
    <result name="fail">/third.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>
```

FirstAction.jsp

```
package action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FirstAction extends ActionSupport{

    private String username;

    public String first(){
        System.out.println("the username is :"+username);
        if(username.equals("a")){
            return "success";
        }else{
            return "fail";
        }
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Following is displayed in console. After the action is called with entered text field again the action is called with empty value hence overwriting my output.

output

```
the username is :a
Jul 30, 2015 12:19:36 PM org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: '/' in namespace: ''. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
Jul 30, 2015 12:19:36 PM org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: '/' in namespace: ''. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
```

Comment: Dojo is deprecated. Dojo is deprecated. Dojo is deprecated. I mean the struts-dojo is deprecated. The standalone Dojo is good, the other one is deprecated. Don't use it, because is deprecated.

Comment: @AndreaLigios ha-ha.. I know its depricated. What else should I use. I have to use ajax i guess.. And I don't know much about jquery

Comment: @GyagueSonam You can use dojo or plain javascript for Ajax but without Struts2 Ajax support, because Struts2 Ajax is valid only if you are using jQuery.

Comment: @GyagueSonam if you don't know raw jQuery nor raw Dojo, and since the struts2-dojo plugin is deprecated, you can use the struts2-jquery plugin. It writes the jquery code for you, that only need to know struts tags.

Answer (score 1):

**struts2-jquery plugin** is the answer for me. Thank you for all the support guys.

As for the answer do the following changes in index. jsp that's it.

index.jsp

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <sj:head jquerytheme="start" jqueryui="true"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> this is index page!!</h1>

        <s:form action="firstAction" id="nform" name="nform">
            <s:textfield name="username" id="username" label="Enter ur name"/>
            <sj:submit button="true" targets="ndiv"/>
        </s:form>

        <div id="ndiv">
            initial data
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```